# How to change CSS style rule within an embedded CSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So how would I change the CSS styles within embedded CSS with JavaScript only?
ex.
if this is in the head of the HTML file:

```
<style>
.middleBTN {
background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

How would I change it to this within the embedded `<style>` using JavaScript only?

```
<style>
.middleBTN {
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
```

I have an element on a page that does not respond to dynamically changing the color using a JavaScript function. It will however respond to a change from the stylesheet or from the embedded CSS styles.

Comment: Please provide an [mre] of "an element on a page that does not respond to dynamically changing the color using a JavaScript function".

Comment: I'm not convinced you need to do what you're attempting to do, but if you did, reading up on [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information#modify_a_stylesheet_rule_with_cssom) would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: Please explain how you are trying to override the CSS with JS, elements should respond fine to js even if their styles are declared as you put

Comment: JavaScript cannot actually do what you requested, because JavaScript can't change that class attribute values. Instead you can actually achieve that with the cssom, `document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'blue'`

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to add two styles:

```
<style>
.middleBTNred
{
 background-color:red;
}
.middleBTNblue
{
 background-color:blue;
}
</style>
```

then change the class of the button with javascript:

```
document.getElemenyById('myawesomebutton').className='middleBTNblue';
```

You are trying to change the style of ALL the red buttons so a more appropriate approach would be:

```
var myawesomebuttons=document.getElemenyByClassName('middleBTNred');
for(var i=0;i<myawesomebuttons.length;i++)
{
 myawesomebuttons[i].className='middleBTNblue';
}
```

Or the jquery equivalent.

Comment: To avoid the risk of wiping out other classes on the same element you should use [classList.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) instead of explicitly setting className to a string.

Comment: @ray hatfield Wouldn't this replace the entire classlist?

Comment: No. It replaces one class (if present) with another, without affecting the rest of the list. The documentation is linked above.